# Get hexadecimal value from accented character

Tags: html, perl, encoding

How do I get the hexadecimal value ("&#X00C2") from the accented character Â? I am using Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ord` to get the number, `printf` to convert it to hex:

```
use utf8;
printf '&#X%04X', ord "Â";
```

Comment: I am Getting This error mr @choroba.                           Malformed UTF-8 character (1 byte, need 2, after start byte 0xd6)  &#X0000

Comment: @depsai, `use utf8;` tells Perl that the source file is encoded using UTF-8, but your source file isn't encoded using UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [HTML::Entities](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities) module, and be sure to escape any HTML-problematic character in a single function call !